# convert/query CSV-value to/as table

Tags: sql-server, csv, sql-server-2016

I have a table like this

```
item    
123;1;2;;    
124;1;;3;    
125;1;2;3;  
126;;;;    
...
```

I need to work with it like with regular table
How could I get something like this:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
123,1,2,NULL
124,1,NULL,3
125,1,2,3
126,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

Comment: So you have  a csv file with those values that you want to import into a table in your database?

Comment: You could use the [SSMS import wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard).

Comment: sql-server-2014 tag *and* sql-server-2016? Edit the tags and limit then to your version. BTW, have you tried SSIS? If so, has it given you any errors?. Check the [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, if you have some fixed length of data or known then you could use `xml node` method

```
select distinct
      case when a.value ('/A[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  = '' then null else a.value ('/A[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') end [Column1] ,
      case when a.value ('/A[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  = '' then null else a.value ('/A[2]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') end [Column2],
      case when a.value ('/A[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  = '' then null else a.value ('/A[3]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') end [Column3],
      case when a.value ('/A[4]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  = '' then null else a.value ('/A[4]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') end [Column4],
      case when a.value ('/A[5]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')  = '' then null else a.value ('/A[5]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') end [Column5]    
      from 
(
    SELECT CAST('<A>'+REPLACE(ITEM, ';', '</A><A>')+'</A>' AS XML) AS Data FROM <table_name>
) A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/A') as split(a)
```

Result :

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
123     1       2       NULL    NULL
124     1       NULL    3       NULL
125     1       2       3       NULL
126     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

however if you want to display `null` values then you could add additional `case` expression condition in above.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **SQL Server 2016** you can try another way with [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    item nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(N'123;1;2;;'),
(N'124;1;;3;'),
(N'125;1;2;3;'),
(N'126;;;;')

SELECT  [1] as col1,
        [2] as col2,
        [3] as col3,
        [4] as col4
FROM (
    SELECT  t.*,
            NULLIF(t1.value,'') as [value], 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY item) as rn
    FROM @table t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT [value]
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(item, ';')  
    ) as t1
) as p
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as pvt
```

Output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
123     1       2       NULL
124     1       NULL    3
125     1       2       3 
126     NULL    NULL    NULL
```